# Currency Format Returns Invalid Characters in Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have a double amount **5190.40**, which when I convert to "Swiss Franc" gives **5'190.40**. However, when I deploy the changes to Azure, it does not convert correctly. The converted currency is now **5Â 190.40**, which is incorrect.
My culture name is **German (Switzerland)**.

I am using the following code to convert currency

```
internal static string FormatCurrency(this double amount, string currencyCode)
{
        var culture = (from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                       let r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID)
                       where r != null
                       && r.ISOCurrencySymbol.ToUpper() == currencyCode.ToUpper()
                       select c).FirstOrDefault();

        if (culture == null)
            return amount.ToString("0.00");

        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = String.Empty;
        return string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", amount).Trim();
}
```

I am executing the code in the following manner:

```
double amount = 5190.40;
amount.FormatCurrency("CHF");
```

Comment: What do you mean by _convert to "Swiss Franc"_? How do you do it exactly?

Comment: I am passing the currency format as "CHF", which is the Swiss Franc currency. I simply pass the double amount with the Currency Format. It works at my local correctly but gives invalid characters when I deploy to azure server. It returns 5Â 190.40 instead of 5'190.40

Comment: Check your Azure server culture settings. Seems like one of them using `Â ` as a thousands separator which is matched `ISOCurrencySymbol` as `CHF` which created a `RegionInfo` from it. I have .NET 4.5 and Win7 SP1 and I do not have any culture that has `Â ` as a thousands separator.